# Query to check if row1 = row2 in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

```
course      |      section      |     type
comart2     :      bsit201      :     lec
comart2     :      bsit202      :     lec
copro2      :      bsit201      :     lec
copro2      :      bsit201      :     lab
```

I have two comart2 but different section.
I want to check if there is the same schedulecourse but different section or the same schedulecourse and same section like the copro2 because it has lecture and laboratory.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblschedule WHERE schedulecourse =
'".$_SESSION['schedulecourse']."' AND schedulesection = 
'".$_SESSION['schedulesection']."' AND schedulesection != (SELECT 
schedulesection FROM tblschedule WHERE schedulecourse = 
'".$_SESSION['schedulecourse']."' limit 1,1);
```

but this just checks for two rows. What if I have 5 comart2 with five different sections? how to check that?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a mysql database correct?

Comment: Why such a check ? compare to using a `unique` constrain ?

Comment: You should have a separate table for each of these: one for courses, one for sections, one for types, and one for course to section maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT course, section, type  
  FROM table
GROUP BY title, section,type
  HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: It worked sir. tnx sir.
but how did it happen? i mean, what is the purpose of HAVING count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE field1=field2";

Comment: doesn't work for me sir. what's your field1 and field2? the course and section?